# Fixed size for QML Dialog

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to forbid resizing for the following `Dialog` window:

```
Dialog {
    id: aboutDialog
    width: 300
    height: 200
    title: "About"
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok

    GridLayout {
        rows: 2
        columns: 2

        Text { text: "Some:"; font.bold: true; }
        Text { text: "text"; }
        Text { text: "and:"; font.bold: true }
        Text { text: "another"; }
    }
}
```

Why there is no property like `resizable: false`? Or is there?

And if I add `minimumWidth` property, then I get the error: `Cannot assign to non-existent property "minimumWidth"`

How can I achieve my goal?

**upd.** Filip helped me with his answer, but still, to make this window non-resizable I have to write this:

```
width: 300
minimumWidth: 300
maximumWidth: 300
height: 200
minimumHeight: 200
maximumHeight: 200
```

instead of something like: `resizable: false`. It's just a bit a lot of lines for such a task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `Dialog` object if you need your window not be resizable. Here is a fragment of the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html):

> Note: do not attempt to bind the width or height of the dialog to the
>   width or height of its content, because Dialog already tries to size
>   itself to the content. If your goal is to change or eliminate the
>   margins, you must override contentItem. If your goal is simply to show
>   a window (whether modal or not), and your platform supports it, it is
>   simpler to use Window instead.

`Window` can have minimum and maximum size. Setting the same max and minimal values makes `Window` not resizable. I guess you will need just to add an OK button to it and you will have what you need.

Comment: Thanks! It helps. But out of curiosity, is it normal, that user can resize all Dialog windows? I can't believe, there is no way to prevent this.

Comment: @retif `Dialog` was meant to be easy to use. You can take any view and easily make it appear in a window. The same goes with `MessageDialog`. If you need to customize this dialog you can use `Window`. That's how it is designed and docs confirm that. Why? I do not know :) Similar situation is with "why do I need to define 4 properties instead of just 1?" Well, that is how it is designed. The one alternative I know about is [`Qt::FramelessWindowHint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum). I do not believe there are any other alternatives.